# .net error when trying to browse tables

Tags: sql-server, management-studio-express

I've installed version 17 of SQL Server Management Studio. When I attempt to click open a database's tables, it gives the following error...

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>   (System.Data)

Any ideas how to fix this? I can view and update views.

Comment: What version is the database that you are trying to view?

Comment: Server is 13.0.4001.

Comment: I downloaded SSMS 17 and installed it, and it's working fine for me. I would suggest reinstalling.

Comment: This error is not a server error, so it's a problem of your SSMS. I think you'd better install a previous version and wait for SP/patches for 2017 be released. Any RTM studio has a lot of "surprises"

Comment: Was I not supposed to delete the Media Creation Tool folder after installation?

Answer (score 0):

Just started working, perhaps as a result of a reboot. :)

**EDIT**

And it came back. I reckon it's a bug.